# In Wii Fit Plus, can I see the highscore for a game without playing it?

Tags: wii-fit-plus

Whenever I want to check the highscores for a particular minigame (or exercise), my only option so far seems to be to play that game (or exercise), which is quite tedious. At some games, I can just fail right away to see the highscores, but at others, even intentionally failing can take a minute or so (and exercises take their time no matter what).

Am I missing something here?

The menus are not exactly intuitive at times, I discovered a number of features and options only by accident, after having played Wii Fit Plus for weeks without noticing them. I really hope a "view highscores" button is somewhere right in my face as well, and I just overlooked it all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you're not missing something, as I was also unable to find anything myself and also unable to find anything online describing a feature like this.

It seems like the only way to view your highscores is to actually play the game.

Comment: Oh well. That's what I call going to great lengths to make sure that people burn calories. "Make them lose weight just by looking things up!"